# Prove that $\log_{2}(7)$ is irrational

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Prove that $\log_{2}(7)$ is an irrational number.

**My Attempt:**

Assume that $\log_{2}(7)$ is a rational number. Then we can express $\log_{2}(7)$ as $\frac{p}{q}$, where $p,q\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $q\neq 0$. This implies that $7^q = 2^p$, where either $p,q>0$ or $p,q<0$.

My question is this: why can't we count for $p,q<0$? My textbook's author counts only for $p,q>0$. Could someone explain the reasoning being used by the author?

Comment: Both integers have the same sign, so if both are negative, it is the same rational number if we choose their additive inverses.

Comment: The internet is big. No reason to write "no" when you mean "number."

Comment: Thanks friends Got it, Sorry Thomas Andrews

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the case $\log_27=p/q$ where $p, q<0$. You'll still have
$$
7^q=2^p
$$
and thus you'll have
$$
\frac{1}{7^{-q}}=\frac{1}{2^{-p}}
$$
which is the same as saying
$$
7^{-q}=2^{-p}
$$
and since $-q$ and $-p$ are both positive, you're back in the case where both exponents are positive.

Answer (score 6):

Since $\log_2(7) > 0$, we know that $p$ and $q$ both have the same sign. Therefore both can be taken as positive.

Comment: But Neal why we can not count for $p,q<0$ bcz here $p$ and $q$ both have same sign.Thanks

Comment: @juantheron: If $p$ and $q$ are both negative, then consider $\frac{-p}{-q}$ (which is _the same_ rational) instead, and continue in the case where numerator and denominator are both positive.

Answer (score 1):

Saying what Neal has already said a bit different: First you realize that $\log_2(7) > 0$. Then if $\log_2(7)$ is rational you can find *positive* integers $p$ and $q$ such that $$\log_2(7) = \frac{p}{q}.$$
You could, of course, also have chosen $p$ and $q$ both negative, but you can definitely pick then both positive. So then, as you note, $7^q = 2^p$. Now since both $7$ and $2$ are prime, you know that this will never happen when $p$ and $q$ are positive *integers*.